# Insert into SQL from MDB file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ms-access, oledb

```
string sqlConnectionString = String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True", server, database);
string mdbConnectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source={0};", @"C:\test\test.mdb");

using (var mdbConnection = new OleDbConnection(mdbConnectionString))
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
{
    mdbConnection.Open();
    sqlConnection.Open();

    // Empty table
    var sqlQuery = String.Format("DELETE FROM Languages");
    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Fill table with new information
    sqlQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO Languages (ID, lang) " +
                             "SELECT ID, lang " +
                             "FROM OPENROWSET('" + mdbConnection.Provider + "', '" + mdbConnection.DataSource + "'; 'admin'; '', Languages)");
     sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);
     sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The second `sqlCommand` throws this error when calling `ExecuteNonQuery`:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'An instance of OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be created for the linked server '(null)'.''.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the variable 'server' set to a valid SQL Server?  Looks like exception is due to connection to the server failing.  The Sql Client connection should not be using JET.  Something is wrong with the code not posted.  use BulkCopy.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `openrowset` is performed from the perspective of the SQL Server. i.e.: it's not going to work unless the Access file is located at `C:\test\test.mdb` on the SQL Server and the Windows account under which SQL Server is running has appropriate file system access.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the Access file will is located on the same machine as SQL Server is running.

Comment: @jdweng works great with `BulkCopy`

Answer (score -1):

You need code before the existing code that you show, to set the server and database names for the sql server. Please check that you have it - and that the server name and database name are correct.
The server name can usually be either text or an IP address ( but leave the quotes around the string eg: "10.1.99.21"

```
Dim server as String
Dim database as String
server = "mySqlServerName"
database = "myDatabaseName"
```

Comment: Since you choose to vote down my solution, please post the code that you use to initialize the variable "server" so we can see what the actual problem is.